# How to set tooltip in older highcharts version

Tags: highcharts

How to set tooltip for pie chart in older highcharts version like 2.0.2? 
The api reference is for the new 3.0 version, and tooltip formatter seems not work in older version.

I tried this:

```
chart_spec.tooltip.Formatter = function(){
return this.point.name + ': <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 1) + '%</b>';
```

};

and this:

```
chart_spec.tooltip.pointFormat = '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage}</b><br/>';
```

Then pass chart_spec to build chart:

```
this.current_chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart_spec);
```

But not work.. Tooltip formatter works for other chart type like column etc..

Comment: why not upgrade, out of curiosity?

Comment: Was just afraid that some compatibility problem might occur with old codes..Is there a documentation or api reference for older version?

Comment: Unforutnately docs for older versions, are not available. Anyway I advice to update to 3.0.2, which has more features.